# zsh completion in the form --host=hostname

Tags: shell, zsh, autocomplete

I have a custom script that requires one argument in the form of `--host=hostname`, and allows one optional argument `-n, --dry-run`.

I have created `zsh` completion, where the optional argument is being offered:

```
#compdef sync-data.sh

_sync-data.sh () {
  local -a args

  args+=(
    '(-n --dry-run)'{-n,--dry-run}'[show what would have been transferred]'
  )

  _arguments $args && return
}

_sync-data.sh "$@"
```

But how can I add the required `--host=hostname`, so that:

1. it is completed as first argument
2. the part after `=` is completed from my `_hosts` completions
3. `--dry-run` is only offered for completion after the required option `--host=` is provided
4. after `--host=hostname` is provided, and optionally `--dry-run`, not other completions are offered (ie, no local filenames).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1+2) Add something like the following as a parameter to _arguments:

```
    '--host=[specify host]:host:_hosts'
```

The part in square brackets is a description that can likely be improved.

3. Make adding `--dry-run` to `args` conditional. `(( CURRENT > 2 ))` adds it from the second word on. `(( $words[(I)--host*] ))` checks for the presence of `--host` on the command-line. It depends what is appropriate.
4. That should be the default situation.

You've go some superfluous elements in your function. There's no need to define a `_sync-data.sh` as the entire contents of the file and then call it. That's only useful when you have multiple functions defined from the one. autoloadable functions are already a function. Also, the `&& return` is superfluous. Functions pass on the return status of the last command.

The whole code as per comment request:

```
#compdef sync-data.sh

local -a args

(( $words[(I)--host*] )) && args+=(
  '(-n --dry-run)'{-n,--dry-run}'[show what would have been transferred]'
)

_arguments $args \
  '--host=[specify host]:host:_hosts'
```

Comment: where exactly should I add the conditional? Could you please copy paste the whole code, including the optimizations you suggest (removing superfluous code) ?